# What is Needed for Cantor-Bernstein-Schröder Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The $CBS$ Theorem is a superb tool to prove the equality of size of two infinite sets.  Inject $A$ in $B$, inject $B$ in $A$, done.

When thinking in naïve set theory one often is unaware of the full extent of one's assumptions.

What are the axioms (fragment of $ZFC$) required to allow for the $CBS$ Theorem?

Comment: Why  this fast down vote???

Comment: For starters, you don’t need $\mathsf{AC}$ at all: the theorem is independent of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of this, but I took a look at the proof and it seems that we're using the following axioms:

- Union
- Pairing
- Product
- $\Sigma_0$-Comprehension
- Infinity
- Extensionality

I couldn't see any use of Replacement anywhere, and the only use of Power Set was to make sure that products exist (to e.g. define our bijection), so might as well just use that. So we've left out full Power Set, Replacement, Foundation and Choice.

If you're not interested in a fine-grained answer, $\textsf Z$ works as well ($\textsf{ZFC}$ without Replacement and Choice).

Comment: You're right, and Replacement is not needed. You already assume that the functions are given and their range is a subclass of a given set. So using $\Sigma_0$-separation you certainly get that the range is a set.