# Axiom of Choice and $\mathfrak c = 2^ {\aleph_0}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question about the famous Cantor equality

$$\mathfrak{c} = 2^ {\aleph_0}$$

Does the proof use Axiom of Choice at all?

It appears to me that the CBS Theorem is all that's needed (so no AC needed),

BUT AC may play a role in setting up the injections (from $\mathfrak c$ to $2^ {\aleph_0}$ and from $2^ {\aleph_0}$ to $\mathfrak c$).

related: 
[Requirements for Cantor Bernstein Schroder Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2026383/what-is-needed-for-cantor-bernstein-schr%C3%B6der-theorem/)

Answer (score 2):

No, AC isn't needed for this equality. An injection $\mathfrak{c}\to 2^{\aleph_0}$ is done by decomposing a number in base $2$( choosing a system to avoid redudancies, for instance saying that there should be no infinite sequence of $1$'s), and an injection $2^{\aleph_0}\to \mathfrak{c}$ associates to a sequence the number whose ternary expansion is that sequence.

The existence and unicity (under certain conditions) of binary and ternary decompositions imply that these are well-defined and injective, and these do not need the axiom of choice

Comment: I am most concerned about the $\mathfrak{c} \to 2^ {\aleph_0}$ injection; in that most of the members of $\mathfrak{c}$ are **not** computable.  Thinking about it, neither the converse injection sounds much more solid.  Sure we can use *reductio ad absurdum*, but generalized TertiumNonDatur is equivalent to AC.  Once you go more rigorous than the naïve/intutionist view things quickly get complicated.

Comment: There is no issue of computability here. You can prove without the use of AC that any real number (between $0$ and $1$ to simplify the argument) can be written uniquely as a sum $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{e_i}{2^i}$ where the $e_i\in \{0,1\}$ and the $e_i$'s are not all eventually $1$'s. This is a theorem without AC, and it does not matter whether given $x$, the associated $(e_i)$ is computable or not (cont.)

Comment: As for the second injection, you can prove a similar result with $2$'s replaced with $3$'s, and $e_i\in \{0,1,2\}$. The uniqueness of this writing implies that if you have two distinct sequences $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ and $(b_n)_{n\geq 1}$ of $0$'s and $1$'s, then $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{a_i}{3^i}\neq \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{b_i}{3^i}$. This is again a theorem without AC. If you want more information then you can ask for the proof of said theorem or look it up (cont)

Comment: Moreover I can't see why you are mentioning reductio ad absurdum or the law of excluded middle, which are implied by the axiom of choice but certainly do not imply it, and are commonly used in classical logic. Now obviously if you work in intuitionism, you don't have these logical principles, and then obviously some theorems of classical logic will fail, maybe the one you're asing about fails there. But then you need to make this clear in your question, saying "Is this theorem valid in intuitionistic logic? ". Since you did not, I used theorems of classical logic, without AC

Comment: Yes, but for a the most numbers you don't know the $e_i 's$  So if you don't "know" your codomain" how do you "know" your function?  And you do have to use the TND.  Because I cannot give you one example where your proposed injection fails, you argue that the injection is true.  But only thing you have is "not(not(p)) for any x", rather than "p for any x" because most of x's you cannot even give.

Comment: You know that the codomain is included in $2^{\aleph_0}$ and that's all that's needed (moreover you can actually determine the exact codomain, although it's not needed here). Yes, you probably use the law of excluded middle, but as I said, as you didn't mention otherwise, I assumed you asked a question in classical logic in ZF, so I answered in classical logic in ZF. Now I don't know if this theorem holds in intuitionistic logic, but that wasn't your question. To make it clear now : do you want an answer whose proof uses only intuitionistic logic ?

Comment: (And if you will accept a proof in classical logic, then mentioning the law of excluded middle is not relevant)